# Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to run the react native app on my phone but I see these issues.
Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync /Users/xyz@xyz-MacB ~ %/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
The build is successful though.
Following this guide of react native
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, I opened .zshrc file and i pasted the above lines .

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

The other answers I see on StackOverflow asks me to paste something similar . What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: what is the value of your $HOME?

Comment: any progress? how did you solve it? I am having the same issue

Comment: Fix for me was, my `ANDROID_HOME` pointed to `$HOME/Library/Android` -- I included `/sdk` and my problem was resolved.